# Is it possible to hide/not display a parse error?

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

Is it possible in php not to display "Parse" error on a web page (more like hiding all error including parse error on a production environment)?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);
```

I tried the above setting but could not hide the parse error.

Example of parse error I triggered

```
if (TRUE) {
  echo 'fail';
```

Comment: How does code which isn't even syntactically valid and therefore has obviously never even been executed make it into production in the first place? What do you expect PHP to do with clearly invalid code other than simply stopping [with an error]?

Comment: you cannot hide or avoid a parse error for obvious reasons, what you can do on the other hand is synctactically check the file prior to `include`ing it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-lint-file.php

Comment: @Calimero, thank you  ... deceze, not so ...

Answer (score 2):

Set `display_errors = Off` *in your php.ini file*. That's the only way to reliably do this, and should be the default in any production environment anyway.

Using `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` doesn't work, because that's executed in runtime, *after* parsing.