# Prevent display of PHP parse errors on screen

Tags: php, .htaccess, ini

Is it possible to prevent PHP parse errors from displaying on the screen?

I added the following line to .htaccess

php_flag display_errors = Off

This line works for all other errors but parse errors.

I am in a shared hosting environment and I edit php.ini using a multiPHP ini editor in the cPanel.

Note - I am logging all errors, including parse errors. So I am able to fix them. I just don't want users seeing the parse error message on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: `display_errors = Off` looks like a php.ini directive (which is the best place to configure it at), not a htaccess directive. In htaccess it should be `php_flag display_errors off`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are absolutely right. The multiPHP ini editor shows the line as display_errors = Off which gets translated to the php_flag display_erros Off in the .htaccess I edited the question to reflect this. Note that because it is shared hosting I can't edit the php.ini directly. Thanks.

Comment: Check that the setting is actually in place by using `phpinfo()` or by looking at the value of `ini_get('display_errors')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to hide/not display a parse error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705807/is-it-possible-to-hide-not-display-a-parse-error)

Comment: The way to prevent parse errors displaying is simply not to have any in the first place. Why would you put syntactically invalid code where a user might encounter it?  If your shared hosting account is where you're doing your development, consider installing XAMPP or similar on your development machine.

Comment: @Phylogenesis thank you for the tip. I checked phpinfo() and it had local value for display_errors set to on. I had a line on my code setting the display_errors to 1 in my test environment. Thank you. :)

Comment: What you ask is not possible. The settings to control error visualization in the php output stream only takes effect once the php engine has started to execute scripts. Parse errors occur _before_ that however, not at runtime but at compile time.